# Is it possible to protect a bulbous lens while shooting?

Tags: lens, tilt-shift

The [Canon TS-E 17mm F/4](http://www.neocamera.com/lens/canon/ts-e_17mm_f4l) has a bulbous front element which protrudes from the lens barrel. This requires a special lens cap which I place diligently while not shooting but there is no head and even no filter-thread.

Can this lens be protected while shooting? If so, what options are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like you are very limited and you would have to create something custom that extends the lens chasis.

According to [this review](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-TS-E-17mm-f-4-L-Tilt-Shift-Lens-Review.aspx)

> There is no lens hood available for this lens (Canon recommends using
>   a piece of cardboard to shade the lens). There are no filter threads
>   provided. And I can tell you that extra care is required to keep that
>   bulgeous glass pristine. Strong recommendation: the supplied and very
>   protective lens cap (shown in the product images below) should be in
>   place unless the lens is actively being used.

and

> The angle of view and the usable image circle (more later) from the
>   Canon TS-E 17mm f/4 L Tilt-Shift Lens are such that a lens hood is not
>   practical - and one is not included. Included is the unique
>   bayonet-mount, wrap-around protective plastic lens cap - with a strap
>   (The manual warns against carrying the lens by the strap - thanks).

In terms of custom you could buy one of [these](http://www.cameraclean.co.uk/products.php?cat=Lens+Guard%99) and chop the end off - and extend past the glass

**UPDATE:** According to [this site](http://deluxgear.com/lens-guard-lens-compatibility/) - under TSE Lenses a L lens guard cap covers this lens